# Google Sheet Not receiving Data from front end

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Fairly new to this process! Trying to set up a form to submit and then have the data go to a google sheet. I used this guide as a template: https://github.com/levinunnink/html-form-to-google-sheet?tab=readme-ov-file, but for some reason the data isnt being received. No errors on the console log either. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

```js
$(document).ready((function () {
   window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const form = document.getElementById('#userForm');

  $( "#submitBtn" ).on( "submit", function() {

    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const action = e.target.action;
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      url:"MY GOOGLE URL",
    })
    .then(() => {
      alert("Success!");
    })

  } );

});
```

```html
<form class="section__form" id="userForm">
  <label>YOUR NAME:
                            <input type="text" class="section__form-input" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Your Name" required></label>
  <label>EMAIL ADDRESS:
                            <input type="email" class="section__form-input" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                            </label>
  <button type="submit" class="section__cta" id="submitBtn">LEARN MORE</button></form>
```

Comment: To confirm, are you referring to Apps Script's console log or the console log on the browser's developer tool? I'm getting a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error when running your code on my end. This error's not visible on Apps Script but does show up in Chrome's developer tools. If you're getting that error, try implementing a CORS proxy similar to what's described on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881141/22353705)

Comment: It seems that in your showing HTML, I cannot find the value of `action`. Is this related to your current issue?